# How to view fetched commits in TortoiseGit?

Tags: fetch, tortoisegit

After fetching (not pulling) remote commits in TortoiseGit, how do I view them?

I am probably just missing something very simple but there is no "In Commits" panel in the sync window, I cannot view those commits in the Log dialog etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is a discussion about showing all local vs. remote branches ([Issue 1847](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1847)), you still have a **checkbox "All branches" in the log viewer**, which can show you remote commits that you just fetched.

[image: TortoiseGit log viewer]